# nginx proxy_pass doesn't work right when concatenating to variable

Tags: nginx

I have an NGINX server running as a reverse proxy for a service I host. I tried configuring it with this:

```
set $upstream_nzbget http://nzbget:6789;

location /nzbget/api/ {
    proxy_pass $upstream_nzbget/;
}
```

But the `proxy_pass` doesn't work properly when I try to add the slash `/` to the end of `$upstream_nzbget`. If I change it to this, it works properly:

```
location /nzbget/api/ {
    proxy_pass http://nzbget:6789/;
}
```

So I think it has something to do with variables in `proxy_pass`. In the first case (the one that isn't working), I'm not really sure what the URL ends up being. I haven't found a way to log the final URI that gets used by `proxy_pass`.

Can someone explain why the first case isn't working? What is the proper solution? Note that I need to keep the variable in `proxy_pass` so it uses the resolver.

Side note: I use a trailing slash in my location block because otherwise I get a 404 when I use this URL:

```
domain.com/nzbget/api/api:password/xmlrpc
```

This is why I use `/nzbget/api/` instead of `/nzbget/api`.

### EDIT 1

I played around with this some more, and I found that this *also* doesn't work:

```
location /nzbget/api/ {
    set $upstream_nzbget http://nzbget:6789/;
    proxy_pass $upstream_nzbget;
}
```

This one is really strange. It's the same string, the only difference is using a variable vs a string literal. I'm not doing any string concatenation here. I'm not sure why there's a behavioral difference.

### EDIT 2

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019399/nginx-proxy-pass-to-variable-with-trailing-slash-fails) might be the same issue, but it has no helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$request_uri` when using it with variable. It's there in the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) somewhere.

It'll be something like:

```
location /nzbget/api/ {
    set $upstream_nzbget http://nzbget:6789$request_uri;
    proxy_pass $upstream_nzbget;
}
```

Comment: But will `$request_uri` have the `/nzbget/api/` portion stripped? I want everything after that prefix to be forwarded; not the full URI. That's why I left just the hostname as a variable; I wanted nginx to remove that prefix for me.